# Display:none change the width

Tags: html, css

I want to use display: none; but without effecting on the width
I have here this filter. What I want when I press in col-md-4 filter to not change the width of it. Here is picture to understand more
You can see the difference between the images width in both picture
Can you please someone help me to fix it! [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHIJ.jpg) Thanks

```
      [![<div class="categories">
        <% @oferta.each do |o| %>
          <ul class="cat">
            <li class="pull-left"><h2><%= link_to o.offer,o %></h2><br><h4><%= o.description %></h4>
              <div class="main">
                <% if o.sigs.exists? %>
                  <div id="myBtnContainer">
                    <button class="btn active"  onclick="filterSelection('o')">All</button>
                      <% o.sigs.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |name| %>
                        <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= name %>')"><%= name %><br>
                        </button>
                      <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <% for item in o.sigs %>
                      <div class="column <%= item.name %>">
                        <div class="content">
                          <%= link_to item do %><%= image_tag item.image.url(), skip_pipeline: true , style: "width:100%"%><% end %>
                          <h4><br><%=link_to item.name,item %></h4>
                          <p><%= item.comment %></p>    
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <% end %><br><br>
                  </div>
                <% end %><br>
              </div>  
        <% end %>
      </div><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x\[i\], "show");
    if (x\[i\].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x\[i\], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2\[i\];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns\[i\].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current\[0\].className = current\[0\].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
  max-width: 1150px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: hide; /* Hide all elements by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
.cat h2{
  color: #c04035
}
.content img{
  height: 200px
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could use: `visibility:hidden;` instead of `display: none;`

Comment: visibility:hidden; not working  it disappear them

Comment: @nour Check in the css whether visibility hidden is applied or not.

Comment: @Vishal How? I add it in the css file instead of display: none; and it hide all of them. it just leave big space

Comment: @nour i don't understand your question, what you want to do?

Comment: @Vishal I want to use  display: none; without changing the width

Comment: Without changing width means, 2 images should fit in the one row?

Answer (score 6):

The **`display: none`** is used to hide elements without deleting them. It does **not take up any space**.

The **`visibility: hidden`** is also hides an element, but affects the layout i.e. **takes up space**. Let us see an example

also I am attached the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         h3.d-none {
            display:none;
         }
         h3.v-hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div>
      <h2>display:none</h2>
      <h3 class="d-none">This is a hidden heading with display:none</h3>
      <p>The hidden heading doesn't take up space after hiding it.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
      <h2>visible:hidden</h2>
      <h3 class="v-hidden">This is a hidden heading with visible:hidden</h3>
      <p>The hidden heading takes up space even after hiding it.</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

> **new snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
      <style>
      .parent-div {
      height: 100px;
      width:100px;
      }
         .child-div {
            display:none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
<div>
      <h2>display:none with space</h2>
     <div class="parent-div"> <h3 class="child-div">This is a hidden heading with display:none</h3></div>
      <p>The hidden heading take up space after hiding it.</p>
      <p>Note: you can give height & width of parent div and <code>display:none</code> to child div.</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nour please check my new solution for you i add snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Display:none actually removes the element to be rendered.

As said before, visibility:hidden is the way to go. It calculates the item as if it would be shown but does not show it (like, sets the opacity to 0)

Comment: No it disappear them

Answer (score 0):

Display None will remove the node from the DOM rather than using display none use visibility hidden.

and make sure to verify that the visibility hidden property is correctly applied you can verify this by inspect Element f+12 in browser