# One to many relationship fom_for take the last 3 from all the model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, one-to-many, form-for

I have one to many relationship(oferta have many sigs) and I want to show the last three sigs from all the oferta

I tried this code but it show the last 3 sigs from each oferta

In home index.erb

```
<% @oferta.each do |o| %>
  <% if o.sigs.exists? %>
    <% for item in o.sigs.order("created_at asc").last(3).each %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="coll">
          <br>
          <%= link_to item do %>
            <%= image_tag item.image.url(), skip_pipeline: true ,id: "img",height: "200px"%>
          <% end %>
          <h4><%=link_to item.name,item %></h4>
          <p id="comment"><%= item.comment %></p>
          <%= link_to "read more..", item %> 
          <p id="price"><%= item.price %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller

```
def index
  @oferta = Ofertum.unscoped.first(3)
end
```

In ofertum model

```
has_many :sigs
```

In sig model

```
belongs_to :ofertum
```

Comment: In your controller, add `@last_3_sigs = Sigs.last(3)` and use where needed. Your view is actually going through each oferta before requesting 3 last sigs (of each)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. where to write in the form?

Comment: I don't see any form in your index.erb

Comment: Here how I used it  <% for item in o.sigs.order("created_at asc").last(3).each %>

Comment: If you just want to show these three sigs, scrap the three first lines and 2 of the 3 last `<% end %>` and add first line `<% @last_3_sigs.each do |item| %>`

Comment: write this code in your controller action `@sighs = Sig.joins(:ofertum).limit(3).order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: with my comment answer?

Comment: Both of them work

Comment: @nour Okay, i thought i will put it in answer and you will upvote and accept it :D

Comment: You can add it as answer so I can give you credit

Comment: I have different question do you think you can answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460334/displaynone-change-the-width/57460856#57460856

Comment: Commented over there, try to mention me in comment so i can get notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in both ways,

```
@last_3_sigs = Sigs.last(3)
```

for getting latest records first use this

```
@last_3_sigs = Sig.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
```